# Frequent stalls when using Chromium. RPi-3

Tags: pi-3

When using Chromium the raspberry pi-3 is stalling and freezing.  CPU window at time of freeze is typically around 45-55%.   Device doesn’t appear to be hot.  I’m going to change browsers to see if this helps, but wondered if this was common on this device? Secondly, is there a way other than a manual unplug to gracefully shutdown.  I’m new to the Linux world and I tried Ctrl+alt+del with little hope and luck.  I don’t want to corrupt my disk and lose my data and python scripts.

Comment: Browser stalls are possible on any device and browser, it's just a matter of finding a website bloated enough to load whatever cores and RAM you have available, and RPi doesn't have much. Or do you mean your system hangs up forever?

Comment: Hangs forever.  Have to do a manual power off on Raspberry Pi 3

Comment: Concerned it might be a bad memory module on board.  But it’s been up all night with no issues.  When I open a second browser tab or it has large data to process, flash videos embedded high res graphics or several pics it’s shot.  If I’m working on a program than I’m just praying it saved and all my work isn’t corrupted on disk.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitively not normal to have browser-induced system crashes. If you suspect bad memory chips, you can try `apt-get install memtester` and make a few test runs. Also, if you're not using the official power adapter, try to get one, or at least a good one: bad power supplies are by far the most common source of hardware problems.

Linux equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is typing `reisub` while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) has a description of each individual command if you're interested.